# Proving that a basis of an $n$-dimensional linear space must have $n$ linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Okay, I understand that a property of the basis is that a $n$-dimensional linear space has to have $n$ linearly independent vectors. I don't know how to write a proof for this though.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly it is you are trying to prove.

Comment: that a set with n+1 elements has at least one element which is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the set with $n+1$ elements to a basis, which will have at least $n+1$ elements.  Then apply the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) to get a contradiction.